# Sending an e-mail with excel attachment but the excel sheet is corrupted. what do i do?

Tags: python, excel, email

command to send e-mail : scripts/**emailSendWithAttachment.py** '' '' '' 'Daily Report' '' $latestFileName

Although the E-mail is being sent, it says the excel attachment is corrupted and cannot be opened. I am pasting the code here so that you guys can take a look.

**emailSendWithAttachment.py** :

```
import os
import sys
import csv
import json
import logging
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE


logging.basicConfig(format='[%(asctime)s]: [%(name)s]: [%(levelname)-4s] %(message)s',
                    datefmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', level = logging.INFO
    )
# Get the total number of args passed to the demo.py
total = len(sys.argv)
print " Total :" + str(total)
print str(sys.argv[0]) +"  " + str(sys.argv[1]) + " " + str(sys.argv[3]) +" " +str(sys.argv[4]) +"  " + str(sys.argv[6])

if( total != 7):
    print ("The total numbers of args should be 6 as EMAIL_FROM,EMAIL_TO,subject,body,Tgt_Dir,File_Name[]")
    sys.exit(0)

if(datetime.now().strftime("%A") == 'Monday'):
        iDate = (datetime.now()+timedelta(days=-3)).strftime('%Y%m%d')
else:
        iDate = (datetime.now()+timedelta(days=-1)).strftime('%Y%m%d')
print iDate


EMAIL_FROM = str(sys.argv[1])
EMAIL_TO = str(sys.argv[2])
subject=str(sys.argv[3]) + iDate
body=str(sys.argv[4]) + iDate
Tgt_Dir =str(sys.argv[5])
File_Name=sys.argv[6]
fileNameArray=File_Name.split(',')


def sendMailMime(emailFrom,emaiTo,subject, body, tgtdir,filename):
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['From'] = emailFrom
        msg['To'] = emaiTo
        msg['Subject'] = subject
        msg.attach(MIMEText(body))
        print filename
        for file in filename :
                print file
                payload = os.path.join(tgtdir, file)
                with open(payload, 'rb') as f:
                        attachment = MIMEText(f.read())
                        attachment['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(payload)
                        msg.attach(attachment)
                        message = msg.as_string()

        p = Popen(["/usr/sbin/sendmail", "-t"], stdin=PIPE)
        p.communicate(message)

sendMailMime(EMAIL_FROM,EMAIL_TO,subject,body,Tgt_Dir,fileNameArray)
```

Comment: command to send mail has not come out properly. Here it is : scripts/emailSendWithAttachment.py 'Sender e-mail' 'receiver email' 'Subject' 'Body' 'Target directory' 'Excel filename'

Comment: You may want to tag this with `Python` if you want more visibility. The `Excel` group is mainly for Excel formula issues.